# Nones on new iPhone not syncing (all usual troubleshooting attempted)

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

Someone please help me with this issue!

I bought a new iPhone SE 3rd generation a few weeks. I activated an eSIM on it yesterday. While playing around today, I realized that my Notes on this device are not syncing with iCloud.

I was on call with Apple tech support (India) for over 3 hours and we go nowhere.

Troubleshooting so far:

- Toggled iCloud sync on and off about 10 times
- Ensured that other items such are photos and contacts are syncing
- Ensured that Notes are available on iCloud Web, iPhone 14, and Macbook
- Ensure WiFi is stable and working
- Gave it enough time to sync (I have about 380+ notes)
- Restarted the phone about 10 times
- Toggled Airplane mode on and off around 20 times
- Reset the phone (without deleting the eSIM) once
- Ensured that iOS is updated to the latest version
- Ensured that the Apple ID used to log into the device in question is, in factm, my Apple ID.
- Ensured that the iCloud account is set to "Push" notes to the device.
  Deleted and re-downloaded the Notes app 5 times.
- Released that notes written on the device in question ARE syncing to iCloud, but not the other way around

None of the articles available on the Web gave anything else apart from what I have already done.

Any suggestions?